# visual studio 2015 replace regex can't work well

Tags: regex, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015

I'm trying to write a regex expression to find and replace code within visual studio.
Here are samples of existing code:

```
        poo0X += poo0vx;
        poo0Y += poo0vy;
        poo1X += poo1vx;
        poo1Y += poo1vy;
        poo2X += poo2vx;
        poo2Y += poo2vy;
```

I want to change the snippet to the following:

```
        poo0.x += poo0vx;
        poo0Y += poo0vy;
        poo1.x += poo1vx;
        poo1Y += poo1vy;
        poo2.x += poo2vx;
        poo2Y += poo2vy;
```

i using the following Regex  like this:

[image]

but I get the wrong result like this:

```
        poo$1.x += poo0vx;
        poo0Y += poo0vy;
        poo$1.x += poo1vx;
        poo1Y += poo1vy;
        poo$1.x += poo2vx;
        poo2Y += poo2vy;
```

anyone can tell me what's wrong with my regex?.my visual studio information is

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change `poo[012]X` to `poo([012])X`.

Refer to image here.[image]